# Can a file be copied to one hard drive in a RAID 1 mirror set (software RAID), and later have the 2 drives sync up?

Tags: disk-utility, raid

I think I read that we can set up a RAID 1 mirror set (software RAID) using OS X Mountain Lion using Disk Utilities, and later plug in one drive and copy a file to that drive, and later on, plug both drives in, and the two drives will sync up automatically?

But I just set that up (using 2 brand new drives), and then Eject the RAID set, and now unplug both drives, and plug only one back in, and the drive won't show in Finder, until I use Disk Utilities to examine the drives, then the drive will show up in Finder.  And then I copied one file to the drive, and plug in the other drive.  And then this second drive blinked for 10 seconds, and I thought they sync'ed up.

However, when I Eject both drives and then plug back the second drive alone and invoke Disk Utilities and look at the drives and then go to Finder to see the files, that new file is not there.  And if I plug both drives in and restart the machine, and invoke Disk Utilities, the 2nd drive show up as "Failed", and the RAID set show up as "Degraded".

So is there a way to copy files only to 1 drive and let them sync up later?  Sometimes, my Macbook Air may have only 1 open USB port, so I can't plug both drives in.  (when I don't have any USB hub).

(I later on tried using "Rebuild" in Disk Utilities, but it took a few minutes and was rebuilding the drive and later on reported that the remaining time is 4 hours.  The first drive only have 5GB or content, and the 2nd drive only has 3.5GB -- only 1 file which is 1.5 GB is missing).

Comment: So you are looking for software like dropbox? Except it manages two USB drives rather than a folder of files and attempts to keep two different file systems in sync?

Comment: no, the Disk Utilities in OS X does software RAID

Comment: My comment was to help me re-tag the question for moderation purposes. I've noticed that your questions are getting a lot of down votes, so I figured if I could help by tagging it software-recommendation, it might help get you answers. As to voting, it's anonymous, so even a moderator can't tell who voted this up or down. Ask us on [meta] for help with voting if you wish to improve your post content so that it's better received in terms of voting.

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking of RAID-1 in the wrong way. RAID-1 is not an architecture intended to happily use a single surviving drive within a raid-1 group, and work out mirroring content later. Ultimately it will do that, but that is considered a recovery operation from a failed state, and it will destructively overwrite the mirror drive after replacement. In RAID-1, the two drives are expected to be both online and available all the time, as transactions will be committed to both. A loss of one drive will not stop the system from operating, but that is considered a failure mode, and as you've seen it will operate in a degraded state.

The expected user operation at that point is to replace the failed drive, at which point the RAID software will make a block-for-block copy from the surviving drive onto the new drive, a process sometimes referred to as resilvering. It doesn't look at files within the filesystem. This can be a resource intensive process, and as you note, can take hours. This is expected behavior.

If you want something that will enforce eventual consistency in drive contents, use something like Rsync. There's an app to help set it up. http://arrsync.sourceforge.net

Comment: But are you suggesting setting them as 2 individual drives, and just use rsync to sync them up?  If so, there can be two issues: (1) even if I set up a cron job to sync them, I don't want to stress the drives once in a while if it is copying 200GB at a time. (2) if the drives are 3.5TB full, does that mean even if I add several files here and there in various folders and now use rsync, it will need to traverse the whole 3.5TB drive for all folder names and file names just to sync up a few files?

Comment: That is what I am suggesting. RAID-1 is _not_ less stressful. If you add 200GB of data to drive 1 alone, and later rsync copies that data to drive 2, then each drive has done the same amount of work. If you try to use RAID-1 to mirror them, then every time you re-sync drive 2, the software will do a block by block copy of the entire partition from drive 1 onto drive 2. It does _not_ do a compare to find differences, so it would copy the full 3.5TB volume. And yes, rsync will have to walk the full tree to find diffs. It is still the most efficient way to get "eventually consistent" volumes.

Comment: And note that I'm speaking of software raid in general, not to any features of a specific implementation. I could believe it is feasible to have an optimized "resilvering" operation that tried to only copy changed blocks, especially with copy-on-write filesystems like ZFS, but that is much less feasible in the general case.

Comment: some people just say an answer of what they know.  Some people have to start by "You are wrong".  I guess this is how they get their glamorous feeling out of life